# create type with different type (custom type, integer, etc...)

Tags: fortran

I would like to create a structure with different type. 
for example create a structure that contain integers in one row and "ragged_Array" in the other.

```
MODULE NewType
TYPE :: vector
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:, :), ALLOCATABLE :: elements
END TYPE vector

TYPE :: ragged_array
    TYPE(VECTOR), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: vectors
END TYPE ragged_array
!This part I don't know how to declare :
TYPE::List_RA
    TYPE(ragged_array), DIMENSION(:)::ListCont
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:)::listInd
END TYPE List_RA
END MODULE
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Other than the fact that you need either explicit or deferred (using allocatable or pointer attribute) shape for the components of `list_ra` I also can't see your problem.

Comment: Ho yes it work, my problem was in the part of using it... sorry and thanks a lot once again for your help !